# UWP Create Tile Menu Links

Tags: c#, uwp, deep-linking, windows-community-toolkit

I want to have for my UWP App on the Tile Menu some Deeplinks to specific things in my App.

Basicly i want to make the same like the XBOX App
[Xbox tile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhGQX.png)

How do i create those links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called the jump list, learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpList` type to access the feautres of the app's jumplist. These actions then appear both in Start menu and in Task bar.

Using the `SystemGroupKind` property you can specify what should be displayed in the system area of the jump list - either `Recent` for recently opened files, `Frequent` for frequently opened items or `None` for nothing. To make this area alive, you need to use file type association for your app.

Then for your own custom items you utilize the `Items` property, where you can simply add new links -

```
// Create JumpListItem - first parameter is the activation argument,
// second the title of the task
var taskItem = JumpListItem.CreateWithArguments( "/Argument", "Write message");

// Set the description (optional)
taskItem.Description = "Write a message to someone.";

// Set the icon, URI must be ms-appx: or ms-appdata:
taskItem.Logo = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WriteMessage.png");

// You may also specify a GroupName to group the tasks
return taskItem;
```

When the user clicks a task, you can check for the arguments in `App.xaml.cs` `OnLaunched` method:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Launch && e.Arguments == "/Argument")
    {
        // Navigate to specific method
    }
}
```